# How to retrieve properties defined in yml in a method annotated with @BeforeClass annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-junit

Hi I am having a spring boot project and I have an integration test. In my integration test i need to start an embedded elastic search instance. I have an application.yml file (src/test/resources/config/application.yml) where i define the elastic search configuration like as follow.

```
elasticsearch:
    configuration:
        clustername: my-cluster
        host: localhost
        port: 57457
```

so what i want i need to obtain this values in my junit test. however i found that @Value annotations dont work over static fields . Any idea how should in order to get the values from the yml file correctly.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PrimecastApp.class)
public class PerformanceReportingIntTest extends AbstractCassandraTest {

    @Autowired
    private PerformanceReportingService performanceReportingService;

    @Autowired
    private HttpMessageConverter[] httpMessageConverters;

    @Autowired
    private ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.configuration.host}")
    private final static String host = null;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.configuration.port}")
    private final static int port = 0;

    private static EmbeddedElastic embeddedElastic;

    private static RestHighLevelClient client;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startElasticServer() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {


        embeddedElastic = EmbeddedElastic.builder().withElasticVersion("6.6.1")
                .withSetting(PopularProperties.HTTP_PORT, port)
                .withSetting(PopularProperties.CLUSTER_NAME, "my_cluster").withStartTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .withIndex("cars", IndexSettings.builder().withType("car", getSystemResourceAsStream()).build()).build()
                .start();

        client = new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, "http")));


    }
```

Appreciate any help
thank you

Comment: You don't. You should do it the other way around. Start the container and publish the host and port so that afterwards you can use that to configure the application.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more . thank you

Comment: Start the server on a random port and expose that to Spring Boot before it starts. Something like https://vanwilgenburg.wordpress.com/2019/01/22/embedded-elasticsearch-junit5-spring-boot/